# ERR 1442:Can't update table 'articulos' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger

Tags: mysql, trigger, mysql-8.0

***Mi ejercicio :*** Hacer un trigger que redonde el precio de los artículos a 50 céntimos, siempre redondeando hacia abajo.

***Por ejemplo :***

> Si es 4,80 se queda con 4,50

> 4.00 ---> 4.00

> 4.10 ---> 4.00

> 4.60 ---> 4.50

***Mi código :***

```
USE almacen;
DELIMITER $$
DROP trigger IF EXISTS redondea_Articulos $$
CREATE trigger redondea_Articulos AFTER INSERT ON articulos FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE redondeo FLOAT(3,2) DEFAULT 0.00;
    DECLARE codArt VARCHAR(7) DEFAULT '';
    SELECT ROUND(NEW.precio*0.5,2),cod_art INTO redondeo,codArt FROM articulos LIMIT 1;
    IF (ROUND(NEW.precio+0.5) > redondeo) then
        SET redondeo = ROUND(NEW.precio+0.50);
        
    END IF;
    UPDATE articulos SET precio = redondeo WHERE cod_art=codArt;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

***Se ejecuta sin problemas pero a la hora de insertar el dato en la tabla artículos sale lo siguiente :***

> ERROR 1442 (HY000): Can't update table 'articulos' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

***Lo que intento insertar :***

```
INSERT INTO articulos VALUES ('DR-004','Bollo',3.3,1,TRUE,'A002','No meter en la nevera');
```

Esta inserción debe de actualizar el precio de 3.3 a 3.0

[<kbd>Ejecutar Ejemplo</kbd>](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PnzHErrf2fZFGZY67K12X/227)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si te piden un disparador, no te líes haciendo todo eso. Simplemente utiliza el `NEW.` de la forma:

```
SET NEW.precio=ROUND_APROPIADO(NEW.precio,2);
```

Y te insertará el precio como pretendes.

Piensa que el disparador se ejecuta registro a registro, no hace falta analizar toda la tabla.

Es decir:

```
CREATE TABLE articulos(
  id_articulo int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  precio float
  );

CREATE TRIGGER articulos_before_insert
  BEFORE INSERT ON articulos
  FOR EACH ROW
  set NEW.precio=FLOOR(NEW.precio*10/5)*5/10;

INSERT INTO articulos (precio) VALUES (1.51),(1.49),(.51),(.48);
```

Con lo que obtendrás:

```
+-------------+--------+
| id_articulo | precio |
+-------------+--------+
|           1 |    1.5 |
|           2 |      1 |
|           3 |    0.5 |
|           4 |      0 |
+-------------+--------+
```

Comment: muchas gracias me ha funcionado pero me lo puedes explicar en que consiste FLOOR y la formula para poder explicárselo a mi profe @DavidJP

Comment: `FLOOR` redondea hacia abajo, y el truco de dividir, redondear y volver a multiplicar, lo entenderás muy fácil si lo pruebas con 10 o 100, con 0.50 es más complicado de ver, pero es la misma estrategia... :)

Comment: vale muchas gracias

Comment: @JavierG.Raya de nuevo: no toques el código de otra persona: debe ser el autor de la respuesta (en este caso) quien la edite.

Comment: vale muchas gracias @DavidJP pero el primer SET debe ser ``SET NEW.precio=FLOOR(NEW.precio*10/5)*5/10;`` no?

Comment: Sí, claro :) Te escribí la función ficticia `ROUND_APROPIADO` para que ahí pusieras el redondeo que procediera suponiendo que en eso no tendrías dificultades. Más adelante te lo resuelvo

Comment: vale muchas gracias @DavidJP